# SQL Query for max value from subsets

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table `bls_jobs` with the following columns: `city`, `state`, `occ_title`, `jobs_1000`, and `loc_quotient`

I am trying to retrieve the highest `loc_quotient` for each city (each city has several `occ_titles`, and each `occ_title` has a `loc_quotient`)

Currently, I can use this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM bls_jobs
WHERE city = 'Hattiesburg'
ORDER BY loc_quotient DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Which does return what I'm looking for (the highest `loc_quotient` in the city, with each of the columns returned), but I'm struggling to figure out how to have it do this for all cities so I have a returned output of just each city's highest `loc_quotient` along with it's data from the other columns ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `distinct on`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (j.city) j.*
FROM bls_jobs j
ORDER BY j.city, j.loc_quotient DESC;
```

`DISTINCT ON` is a convenient Postgres extension.  It returns the first row in each group, where groups are the keys in the `DISTINCT ON ()` clause (and the `ORDER BY` is consistent with them).